# how do i download source code using svn on OS X?

Tags: macos, svn

How can I get source code off the internet using SVN? I'm trying to download Oolong game engine for iPhone OS.

I am on Mac OS X 10.6 with XCode 3.2.2.

`svn checkout http://oolongengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ oolongengine-read-only`

is the command I got from the Oolong Google Code page.

EDIT:

I've tried the command in Terminal. I don't know where the code ends up on my machine. I did not get any errors.

Comment: I just tried your comman  d and it works for me. What error message are you getting?

Comment: Why the downvote? I've tried that command, but I'm not sure where the code lands on my computer.

Comment: This question is probably not that stupid on Mac OS, where (I think) the GUI's folder structure is significantly different from the one used internally by the underlying Unix. What do you get when you type `pwd` in the terminal after doing the checkout?

Comment: @Pekka - The svn checks out. I got it now, thanks to all. @alxp - Are you going to develop an awesome game now that you have the engine? I want to see it! :P

Comment: @Pekka thanks fpr pwd command :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

svn ships with Mac OS X, so all you need to do is open Terminal, navigate to the directory where you want the code, then you can copy and paste that line right in to terminal, hit enter, an voila, the code will be checked out on to your machine.

Comment: "Right into" *where* on my machine?

Comment: @Chris - I'm sorry, I didn't read your answer fully. Got it now, thanks.